# random.choice - TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

My assessment tasks asks us to create a program that asks 10 randomly generated questions; consisting of subtractions/mutiplication/addition, i have finished the code of the randomly generation of questions, but i cannot see why the same error appears, please could some one take a look, the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Open Me x\Computing\Mrs Farakh\Programming\Python\srg.py", line 71, in <module>
    random.choice[(add(),mult(),subtr())]
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

And the code is:

```
import random
import time
global y
y = 0

name = input("Please enter your name: ")
time.sleep(1)
print("You will be prompted 10 mathmatical questions to answer, try your best. If you need help please ask your teacher for an explination on what the task is. Goodluck",name,"!")

def mult():
    global y 
    rand1 = random.randint(2,16)
    rand2 = random.randint(2,16)
    print("What is",rand1,"*", rand2,"?")
    x = int(input())
    ans = rand1 * rand2
    if x == ans:
        print("Correct: You gain 1 point!")
        y = y + 1
        print (y)
    elif x != ans:
        print("You, gain no points")
        y = y * 1
        print(y)
        print("Incorrect")
    else:
        print("Next question")

def subtr():
    global y 
    rand1 = random.randint(2,16)
    rand2 = random.randint(2,16)
    print("What is",rand1,"-", rand2,"?")
    x = int(input())
    ans = rand1 - rand2
    if x == ans:
        print("Correct: You gain 1 point!")
        y = y + 1
        print (y)
    elif x != ans:
        print("You, gain no points")
        y = y * 1
        print(y)
        print("Incorrect")
    else:
        print("Next question")

def add():
    global y 
    rand1 = random.randint(2,16)
    rand2 = random.randint(2,16) 
    print("What is",rand1,"+", rand2,"?")
    x = int(input())
    ans = rand1 + rand2
    if x == ans:
        print("Correct: You gain 1 point!")
        y = y + 1
        print (y)
    elif x != ans:
        print("You, gain no points")
        y = y * 1
        print(y)
        print("Incorrect")
    else:
        print("Next question")




for x in range(10):
    random.choice[(add(),mult(),subtr())]

if y == 10:
    print("Congratulations" ,name, "you have gotten all the questions correct; thanks for taking part.")
else:
    print("Thanks for taking part", name)
```

Sorry, i am once again an amature at python currently, so if you could please help me understand **why** the error happens just as well as answering my question at the same time, that would be very helpful :)

EDIT:

Sorry, i forgot to say, the error happens when the subtr function happens, the other functions work fine..

Comment: Use `()` to call function/method not `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

`random.choice` is a *function*, you need to call it with a list (or other collection).

Furthermore, you cannot put the function calls inside that list, because that would *first* call all three functions, and then call `random.choice`.

Instead, put the functions (uncalled) into a list, pass that array to `random.choice`, and call the resulting (randomly chosen) function:

```
possible_choices = [add, mult, subtr]
choice = random.choice(possible_choices)
choice()
```

`choice` is a randomly chosen function, so we can call it. However, many people will feel that this code is overly verbose, since it needlessly creates intermediate variables. You can put the whole logic into a single expression:

```
random.choice([add, mult, subtr])()
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the problem:

```
random.choice[(add(),mult(),subtr())]
```

Replace it with this:

```
random.choice((add(),mult(),subtr()))
```

Comment: Why is it double brackets instead of single.

    random.choice(add(),mult(),subtr())
?

Comment: @Razor because you're calling `choice` with a single argument, a three-tuple of functions, not three separate arguments. Actually, you should leave the parentheses off the functions inside the tuple - you want to store them, not call them all.